# Is it possible to sample from user defined distribution in Rust?

Tags: random, rust

I am very new to Rust. I want to sample from a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution using the `rand` crate. There may be a way to use other distributions not already in `rand`, but I cannot seem to work out how. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a custom distribution, you need to implement [`Distribution`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/distributions/trait.Distribution.html) for your type.

There is another crate, [`rand_distr`](https://docs.rs/rand_distr/latest/rand_distr/), which implements `Distribution` for many common probability distributions, and you could use any of those as an example of what to do.

For example [this](https://docs.rs/rand_distr/latest/src/rand_distr/poisson.rs.html#83) is the implementation of the [Poisson distribution](https://docs.rs/rand_distr/latest/rand_distr/struct.Poisson.html).

You might consider contributing your Maxwell-Boltzmann implementation to the `rand_distr` crate when you are finished! :)